# ASP.net Ajax Partial Rendering using UpdatePanel not working in WebKit browsers

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax, webkit, updatepanel, webresource.axd

I am part of the developer team for a quite a large online system using ASP.NET(4).

Asp.net Ajax completely breaks down for **Webkit** browsers and we are getting full page postbacks when we should be getting partial only for the UpdatePanels.

I am starting to believe it has something to do with my **Application Configuration**, mainly for the following reasons.

- If I move the ajax enabled controls to a new project they will work as expected for all browsers, including Webkit.
- I created a static .aspx file with nothing but an UpdatePanel,ScriptManager and a button making a literal visible on click.
- I get no Javascript errors from any browser, and i see an http request for the asp.net-ajax (ScriptResource.axd) in both Firebug and Chrome Developer tools
- I tried ye'old safari fix from [this highly referenced thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1252014.aspx)

---

**Edit:** After a bit more testing and http sniffing i noticed a major difference between the test application and the actual application. The test application generates 2 additional .axd files which are not generated from the actual application. These WebResource.axd, seem to contain data related to the async postback. **However this is only the case for Webkit browsers. The WebResource.axd files are generated for Firefox as i can see them in firebug**

---

What i am asking from the community, is any ideas or suggestions as to what could be the cause of this problem and if i am correct to assume that the problem is probably on the server side

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a deprecated  config file that's used to limit the content that bots/spiders/crawlers receive, which was loading by mistake thanks to our lovely inhouse CMS

In short if u get behavior similar to my case, check your  or  configs

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue however my problem was with all browsers and not just webkit.  I ended up going through and tearing up the web.config file and found out that a line: `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy">` was preventing webresource.axd from working properly.  The fix was to simply remove that line from my web.config file.

For a little more information on xhtmlConformance, visit http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/librarY/ms228268(v=vs.85).aspx.

If you scroll all the way to the bottom you'll notice it explicitly states that it causes issues with webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd.